# Seat Map (Bet)a 4.0.0 - All seats showing "SeatIsFree"

Tags: sabre

Using Seat Map (Bet)a 4.0.0 (REST), my call returns a successful response, but all seats are showing "SeatIsFree".
Does the REST API retrieve live seat reservation data, or is that only with SOAP?

Edit:

```
URL="https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v4.0.0/book/flights/seatmaps?mode=seatmaps"

#Payload=    
        {
          "EnhancedSeatMapRQ": {
            "SeatMapQueryEnhanced": {
              "RequestType": "Payload",
              "Currency": "USD",
              "CabinDefinition": {
                "RBD": "Y"
              },
              "Flight": {
                "destination": "SAN",
                "origin": "DFW",
                "DepartureDate": {
                    "content": "2021-09-03"
                },
                "ArrivalDate": {
                    "content": "2021-09-03"
                },
                "Operating": {
                  "carrier": "AA",
                  "content": "1939"
                },
                "Marketing": [
                  {
                    "carrier": "AA",
                    "content": "1939"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seats Services fetched the right information because the data is not real-time in the CERT environment, therefore the seat map may appear as free as the environment is only for testing purposes.

Sabre PRODUCTION are used real time and live data.
Sabre CERT are used for testing purpose.
Sabre TSTS are used to test the most recent features.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.