# Sabre Seat Map REST API?

Tags: rest, sabre

Is there a Seat Map REST API in SABRE?

I see this post mention using Seat Map BETA 4.00 REST API -
([Seat Map (Bet)a 4.0.0 - All seats showing "SeatIsFree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050258/seat-map-beta-4-0-0-all-seats-showing-seatisfree)) - [uberverbosity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16805605/uberverbosity), but I cannot find it in Sabre Dev Studio.

Also, what is the best practice to place "Pick a Seat" in the Air Booking workflow? After RevalidateItinerary and before Create PNR?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the correct service is Get Seats on the following link:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/getseats/v2

To add the seat, make an SSR request on CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ, and the airline carrier will confirm in the response that you can proceed to issue the EMD at the ticketing stage of your workflow.

Comment: Get Seat API, required OfferID, OrderId, or Payload(with paxSegmentRefIds) which does not appear in RevalidateItinerary Response so I cannot use Get Seat API, Is there any solution?
I have added the seats into the SSR request on CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ like:
AirSeat:
 Seats:
 Seat : [
            BoardingPass: true
            ChangeOfGauge: false
            NameNumber: 1.1
            Number: 14B
            SegmentNumber: 1
            ]
Under SpecialReqDetails.
But in Response, it gives me a warning "AirSeatLLSRQ: BP RESTRICTED",
what is wrong?

Comment: This response occurs when you:

Attempt to issue a boarding pass for a flight that has been restricted by the airline.
Confirm the seat number, but note that the "RS" appears in the record's seat display.
This is short for "restricted seat."
You cannot issue a boarding pass for a flight that has been restricted by a carrier.